# What is a JSON provider and what are the different types of providers?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson, moxy

I hear term `JSON` provider every now and then. In one of my project we are converting `XML to JSON` and in other `Java object to JSON`. We use `MOXy Link` for object to json and for other mule implementation. I think it uses `Jackson` underneath.

1. Don't understand really what is `JSON` provider?
2. And what are the different types of providers used in industry and difference among them?

Answer (score 1):

The term JSON provider can have multiple meanings, it really depends on the context you are in:

1. The JSON parser provider (converting JSON String/Stream to JSON objects or events)
2. The JSON-binding provider (converting JSON to/from domain objects)

Below is a link to a recording of a talk that I gave at JavaOne 2013 that you may find interesting.  It is a proposal for a standard JSON-binding API that is based on the most popular open source JSON-binding providers: MOXy, Jackson, GSON, and Genson.

- http://parleys.com/play/525553a9e4b0c4f11ec57729/about